# Rails merging two arrays of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a hard time grasping the logic I'd need to merge two arrays of hashes, It seems I've asked t[his question a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545042/ruby-merging-arrays-or-hashes) in sort of a different way, I've also tried a few other things like the answers offered here: [merging arrays of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947255/merging-arrays-of-hashes)

Any sort of help understanding this would be really helpful to me.

Say I have the following array, and this is output from the method itself, so you can imagine those `:timestamp`s to be `Time` objects

```
[
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 00:00:00 UTC},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 01:00:00 UTC},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 02:00:00 UTC},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 03:00:00 UTC},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 04:00:00 UTC},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 05:00:00 UTC}
]
```

And then an additional array like this, each of which has another value (but sometimes may have a bunch more values besides `:count`)

```
[
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 02:00:00 UTC, :count=>5},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 04:00:00 UTC, :count=>21}
]
```

And result in something like this:

```
[
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 00:00:00 UTC},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 01:00:00 UTC},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 02:00:00 UTC, :count=>5},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 03:00:00 UTC},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 04:00:00 UTC, :count=>21},
  {:timestamp=>2011-12-19 05:00:00 UTC}
]
```

Again, thanks for your help, I'm not sure why I just can't figure out the proper design pattern for this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

it looks like you first group by timestamp and then merge the values:

```
(a1+a2).group_by{|h| h[:timestamp]}.map{|k,v| v.reduce(:merge)}
```

Comment: You can remove `&` on the last block for shorter code: `v.reduce(:merge)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [
  {:timestamp=>'2011-12-19 00:00:00 UTC'},
  {:timestamp=>'2011-12-19 01:00:00 UTC'},
  {:timestamp=>'2011-12-19 02:00:00 UTC'},
  {:timestamp=>'2011-12-19 03:00:00 UTC'},
  {:timestamp=>'2011-12-19 04:00:00 UTC'},
  {:timestamp=>'2011-12-19 05:00:00 UTC'}
]

b = [
  {:timestamp=>'2011-12-19 02:00:00 UTC', :count=>5},
  {:timestamp=>'2011-12-19 04:00:00 UTC', :count=>21}
]

result = a.inject([]) do |memo, v|
  if match = b.detect { |w| (w.to_a & v.to_a).any? }
    memo << match.merge(v)
  else
    memo << v
  end
end

p result
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the `:timestamp` attribute of each hash as its "key", it is easy if you actually convert the arrays into hashes with the `:timestamp` property as the key:

```
h1 = Hash[a1.map{|h| [h[:timestamp], h]}]
h2 = Hash[a2.map{|h| [h[:timestamp], h]}]
```

Then, what you want reduces to simply `merge`-ing the two hashes (and getting away with the keys that were added):

```
p h1.merge(h2).values
# => [
#  {:timestamp=>"2011-12-19 00:00:00 UTC"},
#  {:timestamp=>"2011-12-19 01:00:00 UTC"},
#  {:timestamp=>"2011-12-19 02:00:00 UTC", :count=>5},
#  {:timestamp=>"2011-12-19 03:00:00 UTC"},
#  {:timestamp=>"2011-12-19 04:00:00 UTC", :count=>21},
#  {:timestamp=>"2011-12-19 05:00:00 UTC"}
#]
```